# Unification of Newtonian gravity and electrostatic force

Tags: electrostatics, newtonian-gravity, dipole

Can we not unify Newtonian gravity & electrostatic force? All properties are almost same. We can imagine the atoms of the Earth's core to become dipoles when a body is freely-falling. Thus, due to interaction of body & Earth's dipoles, gravity can be called as electrostatic force.

Comment: The properties of gravity and the electromagnetic force are very different, actually, even though this may not look it, on the surface. The most obvious difference, even for the naive observer, is that electrostatic forces can both be attractive and repulsive, gravity is exclusively attractive.

Comment: @Tamoghna, please accept my answer if it answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

A dipole has two parameters magnitude and orientation. If you change the orientation the nature of the force also changes (i.e from attractive to repulsive), so what you are saying is if you drop a body on suppose say North Pole and it is free falling towards earth then on the South Pole it should free fall away from earth which is not the case.

Electrostatic forces are result of interactions between static charges, where gravity is result of attraction between masses.

Unification of forces are one of the aim of the standard model but adding graviton as a carrier of gravity in the model, the model does not renormalize, And we dont have any proof regarding existance of graviton.